# How to use array as a column to join with a column of mysql table?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of post_ids

```
$ids = array( 
    [0] => 32 
    [1] => 33 
    [2] => 21 
    [3] => 11 
    [4] => 13 
    [5] => 17 
    [6] => 41 
    [7] => 88 
    [8] => 92 
    [9] => 94 
    [10] => 96 
    [11] => 106 
    [12] => 117 
    [13] => 187 
    [14] => 220 
);
```

I want to get a column in database table where the post_id matches the ids in the above array. the table is structured like this

```
post_id | meta_key | meta_value
```

Currently, I'm using `foreach ($ids as $id)` to query a var one by one. This is inefficient with large data sets . Is there a way to query the meta_value column by the $ids array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most efficient way but it works

```
$idList = implode(",",$ids);
```

now your query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts 
          WHERE post_id IN ($idList);";
```

at least now it is reduced to one query

**Update:**

To secure from SQL injection when you populate your array make sure the your database input is safe:

```
// if you are populating your array this way here is the trick
$ids = array();
foreach ($inputValues as $value){
   $ids[] = (int) $value; // this makes sure your input is an integer
}
```

Comment: You're missing the line `<input name="id[]" value="'; drop table posts; '">`

Comment: @Incognito actually nothing says in the question that $ids is a user input, it shows an array

Comment: @Incognito , I'm not using the query for making form. why form...drop..?

Comment: >post_ids

@Jenny Where does your list of IDs come from?

Comment: @Incognito , that ids was saved as an array each time when a new post in a group is created. I need to use this ids several times in other ajax process, also need this ids to display statistics for each group. so I saved this array in group meta table instead of query it every time.

Comment: @Jenny You've created a security exploit that allows me to take control of your database. You can learn about security http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/ as a good starting place.